# Is a pointer to array of run-time fixed size legal?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Can I do

```
int (*myarray)[n];
```

The reason why I want to do that is is that because the inner dimension of the 2D array I want to create is unkown (the outer is). I avoid vector because of reallocation.

Comment: You could use a `vector` and use `reserve` to avoid reallocations, or `array`.... There's no good reason to use C-style arrays.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it and find out?

Comment: _"I avoid vector because of reallocation."_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean, I would have to reserve for ALL the inner vectors (as many as the outer dimension, say 1000000, is.

Answer (score 4):

No it is not.

Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), or even [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

> I avoid vector because of reallocation.

Use [`vector::reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) to avoid costly relocations.

Comment: But then I would have to reserve memory for all the inner vectors. If the outer dimension is for example 1000000, this amounts to 1000000 reserve() (one for each inner vector).

Comment: Compilers know how to handle this situation, compile with optimization flags enabled and you see what I mean @user2370139. There is no significant speedup from writing a mysterious C-style code to achieve the same results. ;)

Comment: @user2370139: But that's exactly what you proposed with your own idea. You can't get away from it, whether you're having a vector do the legwork for you or not.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Actually my idea was to do : "int (*myarray)[n] = new int[1000000*n]; "so that only one malloc is called, and writing myarray[i][j] should yield the right cell since myarray[i] would be, by pointer arithmetic myarray+i * n*size(int). So basically one malloc syscall instead of 1000000 (one for each reserve()

Comment: @user2370139: Okay, so create a `std::vector<int>` of size 1000000*n and translate indexes. If your 2D array is perfectly rectangular (i.e. non-jagged) then you should really be doing that anyway. But this has nothing to do with the decision of whether or not to use a vector.

Comment: `myarray[i][j]` wouldn't do 2D lookup, as `myarray` is a 1D array of int

Comment: have a look at span and multi_span (https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) for a wrapper for index translations

Comment: @user2370139 new not necessary calls malloc() but likely.. but that code is illegal, new returns a pointer.. and pointer may emulate a single-dimensional array only.. you can emulate multidimensional by creating class with redefined operator[] (and helper class for subarray). It doesn't really matter in that case which engine you'll use for storing array - vector or new expression)

Comment: Yes my code incorrect, I forgot to cast so it would be int (myarray)[n] = (int(*)[n])new int[1000000*n]; It's ugly but it worked fine when I used with a constant "n" for a 2D array whose outer dimension is unkown and inner dimension known. So I wanted to replicate this with the opposite case but it looks like it's not possible.

Comment: @user2370139 that's the problem with it, because argument of cast defined on in compile time. Note, GCC and some other complers (Lahey C++? PGI?) do support extension  VLA, that allows to write `int array[n];` But it was wrapper around of dynamic allocation and worked with single dimension only, I think

Answer (score 1):

No. If you are bound to C-Style arrays you can instead use:

```
int n; // array size;
int *myarray = new int[n];
```

**EDIT**

As Rudianto Presetya (sorry I'm pretty new to commenting, don't know exactly how to tag) said, if you can use C++11 or later, use unique_ptr instead of new[]

Comment: But why to use C-style array in [tag:c++]?

Comment: He didn't specify if he is allowed to use C++11 or not and I assumed that he is not allowed.

Comment: @CristianIonescu: Why do you assume that somebody is "not allowed" to use a three-versions-ago variant of the standard from more than half a decade ago?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I happen to work on a project with legacy code where the specifications forbid using C++11 or later (Client decision, not mine)

Comment: @CristianIonescu: That's you, not the OP. I also happen to work on a project that, for various reasons, is stuck on C++03; but that has nothing to do with the assumptions we make on behalf of others.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition significant  portion of industry doesn't allow C++11 features or later because of issue with implementations. E.g. you want use std::mutex?? but most implementations of mutex::lock() doesn't do anything unless you provide a library that  implements it. E.g. GGC's and clang. You're lucky if pthread exist for your platform, but if task not compatible with pthread.. you're busted.

Comment: @Swift: I'm well aware of that, and I never claimed that everybody can use those features. What I'm saying is that we assume you can then correct later, not the other way around. Otherwise why even assume C++03 is permissible? It's vacuous.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition that would be changing over time, all right. Mostly based on what compilers are available today.. there is  no actual compilers that do not support C++03 now,.. though there are C++11 almost-compatible compilers that are not C99 compatible.

Comment: @Swift: Actually, I'm not sure that _any_ compilers fully support C++03 (look into `export`)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition MSVC 2005/2008 didn't used keyword, but worked as it always was declared.. even VC6 to some degree allowed to define  template outside of module. Was PITA for me, because our devs liked to  take advantage of that and I had to "resolve" compilation failure on GCC.  C++11  prohibited that, thankfully

Comment: @Swift: Fair enough. Comeau also had very good support, come to think of it.